# angular-auto-validate alternative for angular 4

Tags: angular, validation, angular4-forms

I'm looking for an Angular4 library capable of automatic validation based on input tag directives. 
Basically the reason is that I don't want to fill by hand (in my html template code) all of my forms with standard messages like "Field1 is required", "Field2 must be a valid email", etc., with all of them tagged with an *ngIf which manages the error visibility.

I think this process can be and should be automated (at runtime).
I found this interesting library written for AngularJs: [angular-auto-validate](http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/)

Do you know any similar library for Angular4?
Or maybe can you suggest me a good approach in order to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a model-driven form with some validators, but it does not exempt you to add messages in your html code...

Recently I use [ng-dynamic-forms](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms). I generated my forms by getting json describing these forms. In ths json you can specify all Validator you want to use for a field and what error message will be display :

```
"validators" : {
          "required": null,
          "minLength": 2,
          "customVal": false
        },
"errorMessages": {
          "required": "Required field. ",
          "minLength": "A minimum of two characters is required. ",
          "customVal": "Custom message. ",
        }
```

By this way you don't need to add manualy tags in your html but you have to dynamicly generate your form that can add others constraints...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll take a look to dynamic forms.